# Is it possible to use align-regexp in wdired mode (Emacs)?

Tags: emacs, dired

Is it possible to use align-regexp in wdired mode (Emacs)?

I want to align folder names that contain a space after the first word.

So:

```
folder1xxx xxxxx
folder2xx xxxxxx
folder3xxxx xxxxx
```

where x can be any alphanumeric character, should become something like this:

```
folder1xxx  xxxxx
folder2xx   xxxxxx
folder3xxxx xxxxx
```

As of now I only get a 'Text is read-only' message, because not the whole buffer is editable.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I just used wdired-change-to-wdired-mode, and then selected the folder names as current region and align-regexp was allowed to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to select the filenames by putting the mark on the first "f" and point on the last "x", `C-x r k` (`kill-rectangle`), go to a temp buffer, `C-x r y` (`yank-rectangle`), do the `align-regexp` there, and then kill/yank rectangle back to the wdired buffer.

More about rectangles [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Rectangles).